# Is there a relation between $e$ and $\pi$ in the context of multiple integrals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, pi, multiple-integral

I have a math assignment. The question statement is "Application of change of variables in double and triple integral. Give the relation between e and pi using this." I did a web search and went through my textbook (Thomas' Calculus) but I'm unable to find a relation between $e$ and $\pi$ in the context of multiple integrals.

Also, what are the applications of change of variables in multiple integrals?

Comment: Is that the *entire* statement of the problem?  Nothing else?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Yeah, that's it. It's more of a write-up than a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing which comes to my mind is evaluating the integral $$ I= \int _0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx =\sqrt {\pi}/2$$

Note that

$$ I^2 = \int _0^{\infty} \int _0^{\infty}e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}dydx =$$

$$ \int _0^{\pi /2} \int _0^{\infty}e^{-r^2}rdr d\theta =\pi/4$$

The trick is to change the dummy variable from $x$ to $y$ and multiply to get a double integral which is changed to polar coordinates and easily evaluated.

The result of $\sqrt {\pi}/2 $  is found by taking the square root of the double integral .

Comment: The result is just $\sqrt{\pi}$. The normalising constant of the Gaussian distribution comes from the fact that the exponent is $-x^2/2$.

Comment: I have it from $0$ to $\infty$ not the entire real line

Comment: Oh, right. But surely the polar integration trick works more naturally for the integral over the entire line?

Comment: Yes it is normally done for the entire real line

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "change the dummy variable from x to y and multiply to get a double integral which is changed to polar coordinates and easily evaluated."? Thanks.

Comment: @aronquemarr I edited my solution and added the explanations to it.